# bootstrap collapse breaks when clicking on elements

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, accordion

I'm not sure what is wrong, since this is pretty much exactly like in the bootstrap website

Once clicked on the first element (List A), it pretty much breaks. Other elements are ok, but once list A is clicked it breaks.

```
<div class="accordion" id="notification_types">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#a">List A</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="a" style="height: 0px;">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#b">List B</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="b" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="accordion-inner" dir="auto" id="a123">
                <a data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/123">123</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#c">List C</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="c" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="accordion-inner" dir="auto" id="a456">
                <a data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/456">456</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've made an example in jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/uycBa/157/
When testing, press List B or C before, since pressing on A will break the whole thing...

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Adding div to first accordion body worked.Could not find reason for this.

```
<div class="accordion" id="notification_types">
    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#a">List A</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="a" style="height: 0px;">
           <div class="accordion-inner">  
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#b">List B</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="b" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="accordion-inner" dir="auto" id="a123">
                <a data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/123">123</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-group">
        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-parent="#notification_types"
            data-toggle="collapse" href="#c">List C</a>
        </div>

        <div class="accordion-body collapse" id="c" style="height: 0px;">
            <div class="accordion-inner" dir="auto" id="a456">
                <a data-method="get" data-remote="true" href="/456">456</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick. Bootstrap must expect uniform structure.

Comment: but this makes an empty div

Comment: Also worked for me just adding some text into first accordion and then  replacing it on show event.

Answer (score 1):

Known error : https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/5849

---

The transition is blocking the plugin because your first collapsible has no height :

The plugin is in the *transitioning* state, and is waiting for the transition to end, but since the height of the element is 0, the transition never started and will not end (I think so). The plugin doesn't do anything when it's in this state.

You can see it if you deactivate the transition : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/uycBa/158/

---

You could stop this by calling `preventDefault()` on the `show` event :

```js
$('.accordion-body.empty').on('show', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

(`empty` is also added in the markup to locate the empty accordion body)

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/uycBa/159/

Comment: this solution is a bit problematic since the lists are generated dynamically. Adding empty class is a bit odd

Comment: @NickGinanto You can use your own way to find them, but I'm sure you can test if the generated content is empty, like your `style="height: 0px"`. You could also check directly in the event handler, and preventing the event based on what you find.